# Find pairs with distance in ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-2.0

I have a big array with a sequence of values. 
To check if the values in place x have an influence on the values on place x+distance
I want to find all the pairs

```
pair = [values[x], values[x+1]]
```

The following code works

```
pairs_with_distance = []
values.each_cons(1+distance) do |sequence| 
  pairs_with_distance << [sequence[0], sequence[-1]]
end
```

but it looks complicated and I wonder if if I make it shorter and clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the code shorter by using `map` directly:

```
pairs_with_distance = values.each_cons(1 + distance).map { |seq| 
  [seq.first, seq.last]
}
```

I prefer something like the example below, because it has short, readable lines of code, and because it separates the steps -- an approach that allows you to give a meaningful names to intermediate calculations (`groups` in this case). You can probably come up with better names based on the real domain of the application.

```
values   = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]
distance = 2

groups = values.each_cons(1 + distance)
pairs  = groups.map { |seq| [seq.first, seq.last] }

p pairs
```